# Maya: How to import fbx using python?

Tags: python, import, maya, fbx

i am still learning python so bear with me.

i need to import an fbx file into an existing scene.

i´ve tried multiply ways of importing, tho nothing worked so far.

what i`ve tried:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def setImport():
    setImportPath = 'X:\Path_To_File.fbx'
    cmds.file(setImportPath, i=True, mergeNamespacesOnClash=True, namespace=':');

setImport()
```

The error i get is:

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 5: File not found. #
```

Next thing i tried was:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.file( 'X:\Path_To_File.fbx', o = True )
```

The error i get is:

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 4: File not found: "X:  ath_to_File.fbx" #
```

Notice the space between the "X:" and the first letter? As well as the missing "P" of "path" ?
Why is that?
What am i missing here?

The first methode is working perfectly on ma/mb files, tho not with fbx.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?

SOLVED:

I copied the file path from the windows explorer, but windows displays the path with backslashes. I changed the backslashes to slashes and now the fbx import works. 
silly me!

Comment: Are you sure `X:\Path_To_File' is really where your file is? Usually it's either C or D

Comment: Thanks for the reply:
yes, i am sure the file path is correct. it doesnt matter tho, if i try an fbx in a different path, its the same error.

Answer (score 2):

I think the somehow the script decode `\P` as a special character. (Which is really common for almost everything start with backslach `\`)

Some possible options you can try: `X:\\Path_To_File.fbx` , `X:/Path_To_File.fbx`

Comment: That was indeed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using windows paths or paths containing backslashes you can use Python's raw string literal. It will interpret the string "as it is" (backslash will be interpreted just as a backslash character. No special meaning). 
e.g:

```py
path = r'C:\path\to\file.txt'
```